# Giving priority to index.php on IIS server with C# project

Tags: c#, php, iis

i have IIS 6.2 and in a website i have both C# and PHP project.
I want the index.php to load as default document firstly, before the C# project.

What I've tried to far, without success , is setting default document index.php at top position.

```
<defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.php" />
            <add value="Default.htm" />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="index.html" />
            <add value="iisstart.htm" />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
```

If i type `www.mydomain.com/index.php` the php project loads perfectly.
If i just type though `www.mydomain.com` it loads the c# project.

How can I do it, any ideas?

Comment: Are you working on an Apache Server? If yes, look into your httpd.conf and search for `DirectoryIndex` and make it to `DirectoryIndex index.php`

Comment: I'm working in IIS 6.2

Comment: Oh lol, its even written in the title. Sorry, the early in the morning. Sadly I've no experience with IIS sorry.

Comment: Please try doing it from IIS manager. In that you can find Default Document option.